# How to control the mask of an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an API that returns the mask of an input based on the country code. What I still need to do is a function that dynamically formats the input as the user types.

For example, the user selects the code +55 and I get that the input mask will be (##)####-####, how can I format the input from the mask?

I tried downloading some libraries but most use the mask in the form of a regex, and that's not how I get it from my api.

Comment: please paste a copy of your code.

Comment: did you try this package ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs inprovement.

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh, this lib work for react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take this library for example https://github.com/CaioQuirinoMedeiros/react-native-mask-input
You can create mask for it like:

```js
import { formatWithMask } from 'react-native-mask-input'

const dataFromBackend = '(##)####-####'
const phoneMask = dataFromBackend.split('').map(item => item === '#' ? /\d/ : item)

const { masked, unmasked, obfuscated } = formatWithMask({
  text: '71680345',
  mask: phoneMask,
});
```